# How to refresh an entire JPA Repository?

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on 2 Spring Boot Applications using Spring-Data-JPA.

These 2 applications share a database and a socket. When `Application 1` makes a change to the database, I have to restart `Application 2` to make it load the changes on its end to.

How can I tell the JPA Repository on `Application 2` to refresh all data?

Thank you for any help in advance :))

P.S. No I cannot just transmit the data over the socket, the only way is over the database.

Edit:

Following Mar-Z's suggestion I added the following method to my JPA Repositories via a Repository Extension

```
    @Override
    public void clear() {
        em.flush();
        em.clear();
    }
```

However the data is still not present in `Application 2`. I have also moved from `save()` to `saveAndFlush()` on `Application 1` to no avail.

Comment: Call entity manager clear method.

Comment: Yesterday I had no time to evaluate the answer. Calling the em.clear() is better then restart of application but is not enough. It need to be initiated somehow. I would implement an endpoint in Application 2 for this. And Application 1 should call it after every change made on the database.

Comment: I call the method and it doesn't do anything

Comment: Nothing? How are you testing it? The successive reading from the database should load the newest values.

Comment: Like this:
`repo.clear();
Optional<? extends TestEntity> testEntity = repo.findById(id);
            if(testEntity.isPresent()) {
                return testEntity.get();
            }
return null;`

Comment: I have tested it either and it works as expected. Hibernate loads the entity first time from database, the successive calls of findById - from cache. After I changed a value with external SQL client it loads still the old value from cache. Until I call em.clear(). The successive call loads the new value from the database (H2 file database).

Comment: Maybe I am clearing the wrong Entity Manager? What if the Entity Manager that is provided to SimpleJpaRepository and the one provided to a repository extension is different... Effectively, the findById method which depends on the SimpleJpaRepository Enttiy Manager would not be refreshed because the SimpleJpaRepository  Entity Manager would not be cleared. How are you implementing the `clear` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253239/discussion-between-mar-z-and-awesomedude091).